# map function is returning elements of u type

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I ran the following pyspark script to do word count:

```
import re
inputRDD=sc.textFile("concatfile")
cleanRDD=inputRDD.map(lambda x:re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+',"",x.upper())).flatMap(lambda x: x.split()).map(lambda x:(x,1))
reduceRDD=cleanRDD.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
reverseKVRDD=reduceRDD.map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0]))
sortRDD=reverseKVRDD.sortByKey(ascending=False)
```

When I dumped cleanRDD, I observed that the key-value pair is coming in the below format:

[(u'THIS', 1), (u'IS', 1), (u'LINE', 1), (u'1', 1), (u'THIS', 1), (u'IS', 1), (u'LINE', 1), (u'2', 1), (u'THIS', 1), (u'IS', 1), (u'LINE', 1), (u'3', 1)]

What is meant by this u'' type? Can I convert it to a normal string type?

Comment: These are unicode strings. You should probably just work with them.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 'u' means unicode. All the values returned by your program is in unicode format.

You can convert unicode to normal string using encode method.

```
text = u'sample text'
print type(text)

# Output
unicode

text = text.encode('utf-8')
print type(text)

# Output
str
```

Comment: I used str casting in the map function and it worked:    cleanStrRDD=cleanRDD.map(lambda x: (str(x[0]),x[1]))